# Deploy web application as a mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web

I already have a web application running on a public IP and I would like do delivery it as a mobile app, to avoid my users to access the application over an ordinary browser.

My requirement is just delivery my mobile app as a browser with no address bar and configured to point to my application's public IP.
In other words, the application will remain the same, and the user will open an mobile app thats is a web browser pointed directly to my web application url.

Since my app is mobile responsive, the user will have a satisfactory experience.

Is there any framework, tool or service to do that?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is have an application with a webview and load your public url in it. For more information about webviews, check this out:- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

You can also refer to this tutorial to get an idea about webviews:-
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is exactly what you are searching for: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html I think you can edit the WebView so that it will show no urk bar and so on.